# AS3 Require Scope Guidance Please ?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, scope

Thanks for taking the time to read... here is my question/scenario, its a quick one:

I have:

```
Stage -> SWF Loader Root -> SWF Loader -> MovieClip -> Nested MC
```

From within "Nested MC": I can only access "SWF loaders root" time line, I can't seem to get access to the stage's functions...

Within "Nested MC" I used:

```
this.parent                 <- shows "MovieClip"
this.parent.parent          <- shows "SWF Loader"
this.parent.parent.parent   <- shows "SWF Loader Root"
this.parent.parent.parent.parent <- SHOWS NULL!!!!
```

Im trying to call on a function which resides on the main time line.
Is there any way to access the main timeline?
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Am I missing something trivial? Im learning

Sam

Comment: Or does this appear to be the proper way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to dispatch an event from your nested MC then listen for the event from the main timeline. Sounds like you're a few layers deep in the display, so make sure you set "bubbles" to true.

From nested MC:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("your_custom_event_name", true));
```

Then on the main timeline:

```
addEventListener("your_custom_event_name", customEventHandler);

function customEventHandler(e:Event):void {
    mainTimelineFunction();
}

function mainTimelineFunction():void {
    trace("success");
}
```

Comment: Corey, Thank you so much, I will try right away, appears to be the solution!

Comment: YES, Corey, thankyou again, I can stop banging my head against the wall. Would you mind voting me up? thnx a million